# Usage of timer.performWithDelay()

Tags: lua

When brackets are included in the listener,

```
timer.performWithDelay( delay, listener [, iterations] )
```

the

```
timer.performWithDelay()
```

fails to delay the function calling.

If I try to declare a function in the

```
timer.performWithDelay()
```

it gives a syntax error.

So how to pass an argument/object using a function included in timer.performWithDelay()?

My code:

```
local normal_remove_asteroid

normal_remove_asteroid = function (asteroid)
    asteroid:removeSelf()
    asteroid = nil
end

timer.performWithDelay(time, normal_remove_asteroid (asteroid) )
```

Comment: Post the actual code you are using.

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

In Lua, `()` is the function call operator (except when next to a `function` keyword): if the object is a function, or has a __call method, it will be called immediately. So giving `normal_remove_asteroid(asteroid)` to `performWithDelay` will actually give it the return value of the `normal_remove_asteroid` function call. If you want to pass argumnents to the function, you have to create a temporary anonymous function that doesn't take any argumnents:

```
local asteroid = ....
...
timer.performWithDelay(time, function() normal_remove_asteroid (asteroid) end )
```

The `asteroid` in the anonymous function is an upvalue; it must be defined somewhere above that line (this must already be the case in your code since you were using it in `normal_remove_asteroid(asteroid)`).

Note that you don't *have* to use an anonymous function: you could also explicitly define a wrapper function but why bother naming it, it is only to wrap:

```
function wrap_normal_remove_asteroid() 
    normal_remove_asteroid (asteroid) 
end 

timer.performWithDelay(time, wrap_normal_remove_asteroid)
```